# How to drag parent from child using pep.jquery.js

Tags: jquery

I have just started using pep.jquery.js. I'm not sure how popular it is but it has turned out extremely useful for some mobile sites that I have been working on.

I did however come across a problem. I would like to drag the parent of the current child being dragged. For instance dragging the whole parent only by its title bar and not from the content within.

Current code:

```
<body>
<div class='window'>
<div class='titlebar'>
</div>
</div>
</body>


$('.titlebar').pep({axis: 'x',stop: handleMenuDrag,useCSSTranslation: false})
```

Comment: could you post your html code ?

Answer (score 2):

What you'd want to do is use pep's `elementsWithInteraction` option, which basically tells the plugin that this element *within* the element we want to move has interaction, and shouldn't trigger movement.

**[Working Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/briangonzalez/pen/khscp)**

Try something like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class='window'>
  <div class='title'>Window</div>
  <div class='content'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.window { height: 300px; width: 300px; border: 1px solid #333; }
.title  { height: 10%; background: #ccc; }
.content{ height: 90%; background: #eee }
.top    { z-index: 100 }
```

**JS**

```
$('.window').pep({
  elementsWithInteraction: '.content',
  initiate: function(){ 
    $('.window.top').removeClass('top');
    this.$el.addClass('top');
  }
});
```

I've also added in a little logic which tells the window with the clicked title bar to move to the top.